# Changing lower bound of array with ReDim gives subscript error

Tags: vba, excel

I have a situation where it would be useful to re-dim an array by changing the lower bound of the array, but it gives me a subscript error. Just wondered if anyone else had come across this behaviour?

```
Sub test()
Dim arr() As Integer
ReDim arr(1 To 10)
ReDim Preserve arr(2 To 11)
End Sub
```

Comment: The issue is with redim Preserve you can only change the last variable.  Not both.  To do this and keep the values you must iterate and put in new array.

Comment: You can't change the lower bound of an array when using `Redim Preserve` - you can only change the upper bound of the last dimension. (note if the variable was actually declared as a variant you can change the lower bound of the last dimension too)

Answer (score 0):

You cant do that, as this would mean an array with a base of 2, which isnt allowed as you've declared it as starting at 1, you could create a new array and transfer 1 to 10 in the position of 2 to 11.  I believe that to be correct any how :)

Comment: No, you can create an array that is from 2 to 11, without the 0 and 1 space.